# Unit Testing spark dataframes transformation chaining

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am very new to scala spark ecosystem and wondering what would be the best way to unit test a chained dataframe transformation.So here is code sample of the method that I would like to test

```
def writeToParquet(spark: SparkSession, dataFrame: DataFrame, col1: DataType1, col2:DataType2): Unit {
    dataFrame
        .withColumn("date", some_columnar_date_logic)
        .withColumn("hour", some_more_functional_logic)
        .... //couple more transformation logic
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .partitionBy("col1", "col2", "col3")
        .parquet("some hdfs/s3/url")        
}
```

The problem is parquet is of `Unit` return type which makes testing difficult.
The problem is further amplified by the fact that, transformations are immutable in nature, which makes mocking and spying a bit difficult

To create dataframe, I have dumped test dataset in csv

Comment: Did you checked my below answer? Did it fit into your case if not please inform me how to help to fit it into your case

Comment: Hi, it will be helpful if you can modify my example so that I can relate more closely to it.

Comment: Kindly check it now. I believe it do what you need.

Comment: Did you checked my answer?

Comment: Hi, I checked, I am still confused about the writing to Parquet file is concerned. Currently, I am trying to mock the DataFrame and verify the number of times the method has been called. Writing shell script is not really an ideal solution

Comment: What about compare the number of written rows and the dataframe count?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? What is the concern for you?

Comment: Hi, I have found an answer that worked for me. Thank you for initial directions :)

Comment: I believe this is similar what I informed you to separate the logic and the writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first thing that I figured out in testing dataframe is to separate out Transformation and IOs

So for the above scenarios
we can divide the above chain into three parts

```
class Coordinator {
    def transformAndWrite(dataframe: Dataframe): Unit = {
transformedDf = dataFrame
        .withColumn("date", some_columnar_date_logic)
        .withColumn("hour", some_more_functional_logic)
        .... //couple more transformation logic
```

```
partitionedDfWriter = transformedDf.write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .partitionBy("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

and

```
partitionedDfWriter.parquet("some hdfs/s3/url")
}
```

now we can move them to three separate classes,

`DFTransformer` , `DFPartitioner` 
and 
`DataFrameParquetWriter extends ResourceWriter`

So the code would become something like this

```
class DFTransformer {
    def transform(dataframe:DataFrame): Dataframe = {
        return dataFrame
        .withColumn("date", some_columnar_date_logic)
        .withColumn("hour", some_more_functional_logic)
        .... //couple more transformation logic

}
```

```
class DfPartitioner {
    def partition(dataframe: DataFrame): DataFrameWriter = {
        return dataframe.write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .partitionBy("col1", "col2", "col3")
    }
}
```

and

```
class DataFrameParquetWriter extends ResourceWriter {
    overide def write(partitionedDfWriter: DataFrameWriter) = {
       partitionedDfWriter.parquet("some hdfs/s3/url") 

    }

class Coordinator(dfTransformer:DfTransformer, dfPartitioner: DFPartitioner, resourceWriter: ResourceWriter) {
    val transformedDf = dfTransformer.transform(dataframe)
    val partitionedDfWriter = dfPartitioner.partition(transformedDf)
    resourceWriter.write(partitionedDfWriter)
}
```

- The advantage of the above is that when you have to test your Coordinator class, you can very easily use `Mockito` to mock your dependencies.
- Testing `DFTransformer` is also easy now,
  You can pass a stubbed Dataframe and assert the returned DataFrame.(using spark-testing-base). We can also test the columns returned by the Transformation. We can also test the count

Answer (score 7):

Kindly find simple Example for data frame unit testing. You can split it into two part. First. to test transformation and you can do simple shell script to test the written file

```
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.scalatest.{FunSuite, Matchers}

class SomeDFTest extends FunSuite with Matchers with DataFrameSuiteBase    {
 import spark.implicits._

  test("Testing Input customer data date transformation") {


    val inputSchema = List(
      StructField("number", IntegerType, false),
      StructField("word", StringType, false)
    )
    val expectedSchema = List(
      StructField("number", IntegerType, false),
      StructField("word", StringType, false),
      StructField("dummyColumn", StringType, false)

    )
    val inputData = Seq(
      Row(8, "bat"),
      Row(64, "mouse"),
      Row(-27, "horse")
    )

    val expectedData = Seq(
      Row (8, "bat","test"),
      Row(64, "mouse","test"),
      Row(-27, "horse","test")
    )

    val inputDF = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(inputData),
      StructType(inputSchema)
    )

    val expectedDF = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(expectedData),
      StructType(expectedSchema)
    )


    val actual = transformSomeDf(inputDF)

    assertDataFrameEquals(actual, expectedDF) // equal



  }

  def transformSomeDf(df:DataFrame):DataFrame={
    df.withColumn("dummyColumn",lit("test"))
  }
}
```

Sbt.build config

```
name := "SparkTest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.4.0_0.11.0" % Test

)
```